# FBA Custom Login Mixed - Access Denied Loops Back to Login Page

Tags: forms-authentication

I created a custom login page using information from [David's site](http://davidlozzi.com/2011/07/15/sharepoint-2010-create-unique-login-page-with-forms-based-authentication/#comment-538)   (Thanks David).  All works fine except in the following situation:

My company has multiple domains - An employee logs into windows with Domain123\username.  There user account on SharePoint is DomainXYZ\username.  When the click on "Employee Login" on the custom page they receive "Error: Access Denied"  You are login in as Domain123\username.  When selecting Log in as a Different User it takes me back to the custom page and if I click on "Employee Login" I receive a blank page.

Instead of going to the Custom Page I'd like a Window's Authentication Log in to open so the person can login with as a different user.  How can I do this?  I'm very new to this and have no idea what coding is needed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To login the user using windows authentication from your custom login page, you can simply redirect them to SharePoint's built in windows authentication page:

/_windows/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F

Answer (score 0):

I think creating the custom login page is in relation to having FBA users from the database. However the you're taking about Windows authentication?

I may be wrong (not been doing this long myself) but why would you have a custom login page for windows authentication?

Comment: in regard to why have a custom form - we are using Claims Base and have both Windows and FB users.  The out-of-box login can be confusing (do I want Widows or Forms Authentication?), disclaimers need to be on the login page, password resets, and registration.

Comment: Ah right, actually I wouldn't know how to do a custom dual login screen. I have the same setup, so I used the windows account as an initial account to set some things up, but once I had a FBA account, I added it to the site collection administrators and now only use FBA, however, it would be interesting to know how to initiate a windows login prompt!